# Cannot download Pillow in Django VSCode project (Windows)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, python-imaging-library

I'm going through Django 2.2 course with Windows / VSCode / Anaconda setup. I've tried to use both Python 3.6 and 3.7 interpreters and tried to download Pillow with commands such as:

- `pip install Pillow`
- `python -m pip install pillow`
- `pip install Pillow==5.0.0`

I've tried to execute this both in is Anaconda Shell Prompt and cmd. Simply put, I get error of missing Pillow package whatever I do. When I try to execute "conda install" it says the the requirement is already satisfied, but it still doesn't recognize the package.

See attached pictures about errors.

[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDk4g.png)

[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSFsL.png)

Comment: PS: Does this have anything to do with virtual environment I set up in earlier section of the course?

Comment: Could you please paste the result of `pip install Pillow` **as text** and not a link to an image.

Comment: @FiddleStix Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\elja\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (5.4.1)

Comment: Also:
RuntimeWarning: Pillow does not yet support Python 3.7 and does not yet provide prebuilt Windows binaries. We do not recommend building from source on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Pillow 5.0.0 doesn't support Python 3.7. So, you have to install **Pillow 5.2 - 5.4** or later versions of Pillow for Python 3.7.

You can check it from pillow's documentation here: [pillow documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Also, be careful of different versions of python installed on your computer. check it and be sure which version is using.